# Getting Oracle Exception: ORA-1017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2008, oracle11g

I have tried so many thing but i can't resolve that Error.

I can connect with my username and password to:

```
Database in SQLDeveloper,
in SQL-Plus,
in Server-Explorer (Visual Studio 2008)
```

and all works fine.

But if i Compile my Project i get that Error:

> ORA-1017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Why is that?

I tried to set case_sensitive to false, but the same error appears.
I don't know what else to do.

My Oracle version:

> Oracle Database 11g Express Edtiton Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
>   PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production CORE 11.2.0.2.0     Production
>   TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production NLSRTL Version
>   11.2.0.2.0 - Production

My Connectionstring:

```
<add name="Oracle" connectionString="Data Source=ORCL;User ID=book;Password=bookadm;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
```

Comment: whats your connection string?

Comment: Show us your connection string.

Comment: What is your `connection type` in sql developer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle JDBC : invalid username/password (ora-01017)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435234/oracle-jdbc-invalid-username-password-ora-01017)