# error : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: oracle, ora-01017

I entered 10 questions in database, with their answers. I started project, I logged in candidate id. After that I gave admit id, it was accepted. After that I tried to open this page(this page is meant to open the test page, which will open questions), and I got error message - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied 
As far I know, there is no error in coding of project. So I had not posted the coding. Error is somewhere in database connectivity. 
(I had seen other topics with this error, but not found help).

```
 {   if(minutes==0 && seconds==0)
    {
       alert('Oops ! ! Time up '+
            'Test Submitted Successfully');
        VerbForm.submit();
    }
seconds=60;
minutes--;
window.setTimeout("timer()", 1000 );
```

}
}

" name="forma">   
    **Time Remaining:** 
" style="border:0px solid white; background: #F0EFE2">:" style="border:0px solid white; background: #F0EFE2">   

   

   

timer();

```
        </div>



  <div id="site_content">

  <div id="content">

    <%
    try{
    int i=1;
    Random rand =new Random();
    int newrand=rand.nextInt(9);
    session.setAttribute("verbrandom",String.valueOf(newrand));
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","java","12345");
     String admitid=session.getAttribute("admitid").toString();
    int aid=Integer.parseInt(admitid); 
    PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement("select verbkey from result where admitid=?");
    ps1.setInt(1,aid);
    ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
    rs1.next();
    if(rs1.getInt("verbkey")==1)
                   {
                    response.sendRedirect("AlreadyExam.jsp");
                   }
           else
           {
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from verbal where qid>? order by qid");
    ps.setInt(1,newrand);
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next() && i<=10)
        {
    %>

    <form action="VerbalResult.jsp" align="left" name="VerbForm">



        <P><b><%=i%>. <%=rs.getString("question")%></b><BR><BR>
```

" value="<%=rs.getString("option1")%>">  A.  <%=rs.getString("option1")%> 
" value="<%=rs.getString("option2")%>">  B.  <%=rs.getString("option2")%>
" value="<%=rs.getString("option3")%>">  C.  <%=rs.getString("option3")%> 
" value="<%=rs.getString("option4")%>">  C.  <%=rs.getString("option4")%>

```
             <%
                i++;
                     } rs.close();
                        ps.close();        
                        } 
                     con.close();
                     rs1.close();
                     ps1.close();


    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
                          {
        response.sendRedirect("CandidateLogin.jsp");
    }
            %>

<p><input style="padding-top: 25px; font: 100% arial; border: 1px solid; width: 170px; margin: 0 0 0 212px; height: 33px; padding: 2px 0 3px 0;cursor: pointer;background: #7D0F0F; color: #FFF;"  class="submit" type="submit" onclick="DoneTest()" name="TestButton" value="Submit Verbal Test"></p>
```

Comment: What's unclear about that error message?

Comment: Coding is right, error is somewhere created during making database and its connectivity. Whole project is running right, editor can enter questions, admin can see results, operator can do its work. Candidate logs in, he can edit his details, but when he go to test page and select a type of test. That test don't open. And give the mentioned error. So explain me where is error and how to remove it?

Comment: You are logging in with the wrong username or password, simple as that. Btw: loading the JDBC driver and establishing the connection **inside** a JSP scriptlet is very, very bad coding style. Read up on connection pools. And even worse: you should never, ever, under no circumstances use the `SYSTEM` account from within your (Web)application.

Comment: For database, it is right username and password"system","12345". Explain me solution. This bad coding style is working in whole project. Error is not in coding. Its in some logical thing needed during database making.

Comment: "*Error is not in coding*" - yes it is. Your *code* is sending username and password to the database - and it's sending the wrong one, otherwise Oracle wouldn't complain. So it's your *code* that is wrong. And **stop using the `system` account**!

Comment: Ok, right, I was looking another program with same name. But now the error is java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset. And right coding is given above. Can you help in it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle JDBC : invalid username/password (ora-01017)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435234/oracle-jdbc-invalid-username-password-ora-01017)

Answer (score 0):

Check your username and password provided into getConnection function.
Verify this username and password from other tool (like sqlplus). 
If username and password are ok, verify if alias is correct (if using JDBC OCI) or that host:port/serviceName is correct (or host:port:sid). 
 For passwords, be sure to use upper case / lower case letters as needed.

Comment: In getConnection function, username and password is right. Checked in sqlplus, password is right. Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","12345"); It is also right. For password, it is entered in numeric format i.e. 111111. So it is also right.

Comment: Password is in varchar2, so any word can come in field of password.

Comment: Please add the code you're using to connect to the database, as well as the *complete* username/password/connection string. Also add the sqlplus example session you use to verify your connection. And please add it to the original post and not as a comment.

Comment: Used localhost - you do run your java code on the same machine where is Oracle server?

Comment: Yes, both are on same machine, coding and oracle.