# Websphere 7 ora 01017 invalid username password logon denied

Tags: java, oracle, websphere, websphere-7

I using RAD8.0,WebSphere Application server 7.0.11, I create datasource, use j2c type username/password valid, set component management and container management to created alias,
I use ojdbc6.jar driver,database oracle 10g. I can connect to database using sqldeveloper.
Using application I get error ora 01017 invalid user name password logon denied. I also pach to wsa 7.0.19. Nothing happend. I used same  application and it was work earlier. 
In web.xml

```
 <resource-ref>
    <description>
    Auto Generated - SDO Datasource connection to DEVRS08</description>
    <res-ref-name>NewOracle</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

open jpa-2.0.2 snapshot-r22266:1084264 fatal general error org.apache.openjpa. persistance.PersistanceExceptions.
Please help me

Comment: Are you sure you set DB url correct? Also check password again. In WAS console you can test DS - doesnt require application.

Comment: DB url correct.Password corect.In WAS console test DS work.Using application have  ora 01017 invalid user name password logon denied.

Comment: then show us code how u use DS, also DS mapping in your app if exist

Comment: in persistence.xml <persistence-unit name="NpoEJB">
  <jta-data-source>jdbc/NewOracle</jta-data-source>
               
                 <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="SchemaName"/>
<persistence-unit> Only JNDI name in application same as in DS

Comment: you can edit your main post, add code there. Also spring beans mapping if you use or how you use persistence obj.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle JDBC : invalid username/password (ora-01017)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435234/oracle-jdbc-invalid-username-password-ora-01017)